# Finding all duplicate rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following table

```
first   last     value
tony    jones     1
james   guy       5  
sara    miller    6
tony    jones     2
sara    miller    3
joe     cool      4
david   marting   7
```

Is there a command to quickly query all duplicate rows.

So I would end up with:

```
first   last     value
tony    jones     1
tony    jones     2
sara    miller    6
sara    miller    3
```

Help!

This is the query I need to add this to:

```
SELECT l.create_date, l.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.state, c.zipcode, 
l.source AS 'affiliateId', ls.buyer, ls.amount FROM lead_status AS ls 
INNER JOIN leads AS l ON l.id = ls.lead_id 
INNER JOIN contacts AS c ON c.lead_id = l.id 
WHERE ls.discriminator = 'AUTO_POST' AND l.affiliate_id=1003 
AND ls.winner =1 AND l.test =0 AND l.create_date BETWEEN '2011-10-03' AND '2011-10-19';
```

Comment: Are the values unique for each first/last combination?

Comment: Yes, they are just first and last names.

Comment: do you want just select or delete duplicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM <table> t1, <table> t2 
WHERE t1.first=t2.first AND 
  t1.last=t2.last AND 
  t1.value<>t2.value
;
```

Comment: +1 Although I would change the implicit join to a explicit `INNER JOIN`

Comment: You need to say `SELECT DISTINCT ...` or change your query.  What happens if we have rows ('tony', 'jones', 1), ('tony', 'jones', 2) and ('tony', 'jones', 3)?  You'll get more than three 'tony jones' records returned...

Answer (score 3):

This should do it efficiently, assuming proper indexing and that the value is unique for each row:

```
SELECT first, 
       last, 
       value 
FROM MyTable AS T1
WHERE EXISTS ( -- Is there another row with the same first/last name,
  SELECT *     -- but a different value
  FROM MyTable AS T2 
  WHERE T2.first=T1.first 
    AND T2.last=T1.last 
    AND T2.value<>T1.value
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want repeated....

```
   select t2.first, t2.last , t1.value from (
      select first, last, count(*) from your_table
      group by first, last
      having count(*)>1
    ) t2 inner join your_table t1 on (t1.first=t2.first and t1.last=t2.last)
```

Additionally,

```
select first, last , count(*) from your_table
group by first, last
```

Will return first, last and an extra column with the number of times the record is repeated

Answer (score 0):

How about just using "SELECT DISTINCT ..." ?
Doesn't it do the job?